# Can I ignore data received on a websocket indefinitely?

Tags: asp.net, websocket

I'd like to setup a websocket as a way to push data to clients but I have no interest in anything the client might try to send back on the socket. Since it'll be a publicly available end point, I imagine people will try to send stuff.

My server side implementation is Asp.Net's `System.Net.WebSockets` being handled in an `IHttpHandler` (Exactly like [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/617611/Using-WebSocket-in-NET-4-5-Part-1) up to Step 2).

Can I simply not read from the socket or will data sent to the server pile up somewhere? Do I need to retrieve and just throw away anything that comes in so the pipes stay clear? Better yet, is there a way to define a WebSocket as read only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read and discard since you can get a `Close` frame indicating that the client wants to close the connection.

Comment: P.S. It should also be noted that the data piles up in the buffer and that if the buffer is full errors might arise (including TCP/IP errors)... It's better to keep clearing the socket's buffer.